# calling mysql query in vb6

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, vb6

I wanted to call a query that I have created in mysql. It is working in through navicat interface. I am trying to access this query via vb6 I get "Runtime Error 91 object variable or with block variable not set"

My Code vb6:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SqlCmd As ADODB.Command

con.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=databasename;Username=user;password=pw"

Set SqlCmd = New ADODB.Command
SqlCmd.ActiveConnection = con
SqlCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
SqlCmd.CommandText = "Stock Movement"

Set rs = sqlcms.Execute
```

I am not sure on the con.open what is missing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `con.Open` but you haven't instantiated the object yet.

Change `Dim con As ADODB.Connection` to

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
```